# MongoDB - Convert object to array

Tags: mongodb

given the following document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": 
    },
    "data": {
        "2": {
            "property": "str",
            "comments": 3
        },
        "3": {
            "property": "str",
            "comments": 3
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to convert it to the following form:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": 
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "key": 2,
            "property": "str",
            "comments": 3
        },
        {
            "key": 3,
            "property": "str",
            "comments": 3
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use $objectToArray, but it results a weird syntax

Comment: Try `$objectToArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      data: {$map: {
          input: {$objectToArray: "$data"},
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              {key: "$$this.k"},
              "$$this.v"
          ]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8tub69DRr7P)

Or, if you want the key sorted, add a [small addition](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Rv5KxIw8hf)